# Add a flag in bash only if the command's version supports it

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

I have a command such: `... | sort -u -V`. It works on many of the latest versions of `sort`, but some of my machines I run the command on have a very old version of `sort` that does not support the `-V` flag.

How can I conditionally set the `-V` flag only if the `sort` command accepts it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can maybe do:

```
if $(sort -u -V test_file &>/dev/null)
then
    ... | sort -u -V
fi
```

Because `sort -u -V` will return an error exit code if it is not available.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this funny command might work:

```
SUPPORTS=$(man sort | grep "^\s*\-V" &> /dev/null && echo Y || echo N)
```